# BigQuery Dynamic JSON attributes as columnar data

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a table with one of the columns containing JSON.

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abc1 | `{“a”: “a_val”, “b”: “b_val”}` |
| 2 | Abc2 | `{"a": “a_val2”, “c”: “c_val2”}` |
| 3 | Abc3 | `{"b": “b_val3”, “c”: “c_val3”, “d”: {“x”: “x_val”, “y”: “y_val”}}` |

How can I put together BQ SQL to extract the columns and attributes of the JSON as additional columns. Need to go only 1 level deep into the JSON. So the output should look like:

| Col_A | Col_B | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abc1 | a_val | b_val |  |  |
| 2 | Abc2 | a_val2 |  | c_val2 |  |
| 3 | Abc3 |  | b_val3 | c_val3 | `{“x”: “x_val”, “y”: “y_val”}` |

Answer (score 3):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function json_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";
create temp function json_path(json string, json_path string)
returns string
language js as """
    try { var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
        return JSON.stringify(jsonPath(parsed, json_path));
    } catch (e) { return null }
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://my-storage/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
select * from (
  select t.* except(col_c), key, trim(json_path(col_c, '$.' || key), '"[]') value
  from your_table t,
  unnest(json_keys(col_c)) key 
)
pivot (min(value) for key in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 1 col_a, 'abc1' col_b, '{"a": "a_val", "b": "b_val"}' col_c union all
  select 2, 'abc2', '{"a": "a_val2", "c": "c_val2"}' union all
  select 3, 'abc3', '{"b": "b_val3", "c": "c_val3", "d": {"x": "x_val", "y": "y_val"}}' 
)
```

output is

[image]

In order to use above you need to upload `jsonpath-0.8.0.js` (can be download at https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/downloads) into your GCS bucket `gs://my-storage/`

As you can see - above solution assumes you know key names in advance
Obviously, when you know keys in advance you would simply use `json_extract`, but this would not work for when you don't know keys in advance!
So, if you don't know - above solution can be used as a template for dynamically generating query (with real keys in `for key in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`) to be executed with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Mikhail. In the last line though I see that you have the names of the columns written (pivot (min(value) for key in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))  ). This means that I would need to know the column names ahead of time. But in prod, I would not, since customers would send me dynamic JSONs.

Comment: read second from the bottom paragraph in my answer - this is exactly what I meant! makes sense now?

Comment: also as of dynamic pivot technic - i have provided at least few answers on this topic here on SO on how to make it work - just do a little search :o)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try those suggestions.