# BigQuery - JSON_QUERY - Need to find a common path for multiple rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to Bigquery and stackoverflow as well. I am dealing with multiple rows of JSON codes in a given column and they are all similar but they have different Id's. I am trying to extract DAYS from them.

Currently I am using the following formula to extract DAYS.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(Column,'$.data.extract.b2ed07ab-8f70-47e1-9550-270a23ec5e37.sections[0].TIME[0].DAYS') FROM DEFAULT_TABLE_LOCATION
```

This gives me what I want but there are multiple rows of data where the only difference is the ID which I've mentioned above `b2ed07ab-8f70-47e1-9550-270a23ec5e37`.

Is there a way for me to use something like

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(Column,'$.data.extract.????????-????-????-????-????????????.sections[0].TIME[0].DAYS') FROM DEFAULT_TABLE_LOCATION
```

to get the same data stored in different rows?

In summary, Is it possible for me to have a common JSON path to extract values stored in multiple rows, given that they have the same char length to find the DAYS?

Here's a sample code. I have omitted most of the irrelevant code as it was too big to paste here.

`{"data":{"CONFDETAILS":[...Some XYZ code...},"extract":{"b2ed07ab-8f70-47e1-9550-270a23ec5e37":{.......},"entities":null,"sections":[{.......,"TIME":[{"DAYS":[false,false,false,false,false,false,true],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[true,false,false,false,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,true,false,false,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,true,false,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,false,true,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,false,false,true,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,false,false,false,true,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"}],........}`

and to give some more perspective, the data in the following rows look like this. With just the ID being different.

`{"data":{"CONFDETAILS":[...Some XYZ code...},"extract":{"e520ab02-6ec1-4fdf-b810-0d1b74fc719c":{.......},"entities":null,"sections":[{.......,"TIME":[{"DAYS":[false,false,false,false,false,false,true],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[true,false,false,false,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,true,false,false,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,true,false,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,false,true,false,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,false,false,true,false,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"},{"DAYS":[false,false,false,false,false,true,false],"end":"23:59","start":"00:00"}],........}`

Comment: Can I suggest that you post some sample (public/madeup) data that shows your source table and what you would like as output?  Keep it simple, maybe make up a simpler problem that, if solved, you could extrapolate to your own puzzle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for a quick reply! Here's the code, I have omitted a bunch of code which was irrelevant, did my best to not loose its framework. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: see answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74116564/5221944 as your question looks like "exact" dup of respective question

Comment: your question is too broad and generic so it is hard to give you more specific answer. meantime check out approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949910/5221944  . it uses classic JsonPath approach. hope  you can adopt it to your use case :o)

Comment: Yeah both won't work as I am dealing with the TYPE JSON instead of a TYPE STRING and trying both the formats, I got the error "No support yet for JavaScript input of type JSON". I am still new to this, I guess I'll have to do a lot of digging. However, I know all the keys for which I need to make the JSON path for - is it possible for me have something like an or statement within the paths? like $.data.extract.ID1 || ID2 || ID3.sections[0].TIME[0].DAYS? I've read the bigquery reference manual; seems like they've only got [], ., and $ operators. Really out of luck with flexibility here. :/

Comment: while JSON type is available  - full support for JsonPath is not (hopefully yet). So consider transforming your JSON into STRING and use available options!

Comment: Maybe using a function coded in JavaScript but callable from your SQL may help?

See ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742020/what-jsonpath-expressions-are-supported-in-bigquery